# UK deportation effect on another country's visa

Tags: united-kingdom

I was removed from the UK 5 years ago because I entered the UK on a student visa and after 11 months I applied for asylum. Two months after that I was deported from the UK. What I want to know is until when am I banned from applying for a UK visa or entering the UK. I heard it is 5 years.

Comment: The tourist question belongs on http://travel.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your title and the main body of your text are two different questions. Do you want to enter the UK or somewhere else? If the UK, then why does it say 'another country's visa'?

Answer (score 2):

You could apply right now if you wanted. However the reality is that you can probably forget about returning to the UK ever again, by legal means anyway, unless you become a highly self sufficient (i.e. movie star, business mogul, nobel laureate, world class athlete, etc...). There are several possible re-entry bans [depending on how you left](http://righttoremain.org.uk/toolkit/legalprocess/re-entry-bans.html), but these are practically nominal. I doubt anyone who has ever actually gotten a re-entry ban of any kind has been able to return to the UK except perhaps by marriage, and even that is considerably harder now.